# How to highlight text matched in document with regex

Tags: javascript, dom

I have defined the following function

`const buildRegex = str => '\\b\\w*' + str.split('').join('\\w*') + '\\w*\\b'`

it transforms a string in to a regex like

`buildRegex('test') => \b\w*t\w*e\w*s\w*t\w*\b`

I use this regex to search a webpage with

`[...document.body.innerText.matchAll(new RegExp(buildRegex("test"),"gi"))]`

This kind of search is something that the built-in search functionality of browsers doesn't support.

Now what would be the easiest way to highlight this text in the doucment? I'm thinking about surrounding it with `<span style="background:lightblue">{matchedText}</span>`, but how can this easiest be achieved?

Comment: Have it worked?

Comment: First, it's usually not a good idea to use regex on html/xml. Second, can you edit your question and add an example of a matched node in context (that is, inside its parent)? It would make it easier to answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting Well, I'm only searching through the text content (no html tags)

Comment: I understand; but the alternative is not to use css selectors, but xpath which allows search for text content.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve worked on a solution, although it´s a bit nasty:

HTML:

```
<h1 class='text'>China is a big threat to the U.S economy.</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
function highlight(text) {
  var element= document.querySelector('.text');
  var previousText =  element.textContent.split(text);

  element.textContent= '';

  previousText.forEach((item, index) => {
          var nodeElement =      document.createElement("SPAN").
          appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
          element.appendChild(nodeElement);

          if(index < previousText.length -1) {
             var nodeElement2 = document.createElement("SPAN");
             nodeElement2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
             nodeElement2.style.background = 'lightblue';
             element.appendChild(nodeElement2);
        }
  });



 }

highlight('China');
```